# Oracle One-to-Many Retrieve Failing, Hibernate 5.1.1.Final

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many, oracle12c

I have a class that contains a one-to-many relationship.  The retrieval was working just fine, then someone touched the database and now the retrieval fails to populate the Set.

The relationship:

**Parent Entity: Permit Period**

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "permitPeriodEntity")
@Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
private Set<SubmittedFormEntity> submittedForms;
```

**Child Entity: Submitted Form**

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns( {
    @JoinColumn(name = "PERMIT_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false),
    @JoinColumn(name = "PERIOD_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
})
private PermitPeriodEntity permitPeriodEntity;
```

**The Actual SQL Generated When I Pass the Object to Dozer (Lazy Load)**

```
Hibernate: select submittedf0_.PERMIT_ID as PERMIT_ID9_21_0_, submittedf0_.PERIOD_ID as PERIOD_ID8_21_0_, submittedf0_.FORM_ID as FORM_ID1_21_0_, submittedf0_.FORM_ID as FORM_ID1_21_1_, submittedf0_.CREATED_BY as CREATED_BY2_21_1_, submittedf0_.CREATED_DT as CREATED_DT3_21_1_, submittedf0_.FORM_NUM as FORM_NUM4_21_1_, submittedf0_.FORM_TYPE_CD as FORM_TYPE_CD5_21_1_, submittedf0_.MODIFIED_BY as MODIFIED_BY6_21_1_, submittedf0_.MODIFIED_DT as MODIFIED_DT7_21_1_, submittedf0_.PERIOD_ID as PERIOD_ID8_21_1_, submittedf0_.PERMIT_ID as PERMIT_ID9_21_1_ from TU_SUBMITTED_FORM submittedf0_ where submittedf0_.PERMIT_ID=? and submittedf0_.PERIOD_ID=?
```

So hibernate is calling the SQL to load this data lazily when I call Dozer to map it to my new bean, but in the debugger I can see the Entity's set, though now initialzed after the dozer mapping, is empty even though it should have three records.

This has been working literally for two weeks now, and I haven't changed any code.  Any idea why this would suddenly stop working?

Comment: I found the problem by changing load type to eager.  Hibernate is reversing the join columns.  The stage data we had been given had permit / period combinations of 1,1 2,2 3,3.  Now that we are seeing real data, it fails because it's trying to join on permitId=periodId and vice versa.

Comment: I haven't gotten back to my computer, but I would assume that the issue is referenced column name needs to be added to my join columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that our test data had been set up with equal permitId and periodId values (1,1 2,2 3,3).  When we wiped the database and started using data generated by the application, the PERMIT_ID and PERIOD_ID were reversed across the relationship because I did not include a referencedColumnName attribute.  When I changed the load to EAGER the  join statement made it very obvious what was wrong (OUTER JOIN ON PermitPeriod.permitId = SubmittedForm.periodId AND PermitPeriod.periodId = SubmittedForm.permitId).

A runtime error would have been nice, Hibernate.  Instead, you mapped the columns together at random even though they were named exactly the same thing.